# Change of base for fractional numbers in O(N) time

Tags: java

I apologize. This question is part of a programming assignment. We're asked to implement
a method that changes a *fraction* f from base A to base B with P digits of precision. 
The function has signature

`baseChanger(int[] f, int A, int B, int P)`.

For example, the decimal 3.14159 has fraction 0.14159 and is represented as an array:

```
int[] frac = {1,4,1,5,9};
```

A fraction in base-16 -- 0.3BA07 -- would be written

```
int[] frac = {3,11,10,0,7};
```

The binary fraction 0.01 converted to a decimal fraction is 0.25, and a test of the conversion function would look like this:

```
int[] from = {0,1};
int[] to = {2,5};

@Test
    assertArrayEquals(to, baseChanger(from, 2, 10, 2));
```

This is the algorithm we were asked to implement:

```
/*      
 * for (i < P) {
 *   1. Keep a carry, initialize to 0.
 *   2. From right to left:
 *      a. x = multiply the ith digit by B and add the carry
 *      b. the new ith digit is x % A
 *      c. carry = x / A
 *   3. output[i] = carry 
 * 
 * @param f The input array to translate. This array is not mutated.
 * @param A The base that the input array is expressed in.
 * @param B The base to translate into.
 * @param P The number of digits of precision the output should
 *                   have.
 * @return An array of size P expressing digits in B.
 */
```

So with "from" and "to" as above, this would mean doing the following:

1. Create an array that can hold P digits:

   int[] output = new int[P]; // output = {0, 0}
2. Take the rightmost digit of "from":

   {0, 1 <== }
3. Multiply that digit by B (10 here) and add the carry (zero, currently), and assign to x:

   x <-- 1 x 10 + 0 = 10
4. *Replace* the rightmost digit (currently 1) with x mod A (2 here):

   {0, **0** <== }
5. Calculate the carry, which is x / A:

   carry <-- 10 / 2 = 5
6. Assign carry to the 0th slot in output:

   output[0] <-- carry

   output: {**5** <==, 0}

This procedure is repeated once more, and output is now

```
output: {2,5}
```

But notice that the digits are in the wrong order and are output from *least significant* to *most significant*!

Also, (more importantly), what would be done for a conversion from a decimal fraction like 0.3 to binary? Suppose you wanted, say, 12 digits of precision. There is no exact binary representation, of course, so what would you do here, especially since the least significant digits come out *first*?

```
from = {3}
```

I'm not sure where to start and would appreciate some advice. Remember that these numbers are fractions, not whole numbers and that the algorithm has to finish in *linear* time.

Comment: As an aside, this is a bad example of what to write in a Javadoc comment. The Javadoc for such a method should document what the method does, but not how it does it, which may change due to an improved algorithm being discovered (in general).

Comment: This is similar to a program that I've written (it uses similar algortithm) but it uses `String` to store the result. Shall I post it?

Comment: Please clarify about the `baseChanger(int[] f, int A, int B, int P)` method. Are there requirements about the length of the `f` array? If you are implementing long arithmetics, then you anyway deal with at least `P` Karatsuba multiplications. It gives you about `O(|f| ^ 1.585 * P)` complexity.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev Zero or more entries in f, and sane things like 0 <= f[i] < A; and A, B positive. A recursive solution seems too expensive...can't one just cast to a longer type? (2^31 - 1) * (2^31 - 1) <= 2^62.

Comment: @user1505713. So, if *f* can be of any length, you should implement long arithmetics. Linear time conversion is impossible. And what recursive solution do you mean?

Comment: Did you try to google: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55744.html? Or this is incorrect?

Comment: @Mikhail I read through it, but his example uses floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev I might have a solution (that runs in O(NP) time); please see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I *think* it finishes in *O(N) time*. I've added to the versatility of the algorithm. Moreover, **Negative radixes are IMPRACTICAL**

The following method converts a number in the decimal base to that mentioned in `radix`:

```
/**
 * This method returns an array with <code>precs</code> elements conating the
 * required fractional part in the base <code>radix</code>
 *
 * @param frac A <code>float</code> that contains the fractional part 
 * (and fractional part only!!) in decimal number system.
 * @param radix The base to which it has to be converted (must be (+) ve).
 * @param precs The number of digits required i.e. precision.
 * 
 * @return A <code>int[]</code> that contains the digits(eqivalent).
 */
public static int[] toRadix(float frac, int radix, int precs)
{
    if(radix < 2) return null;
    //Only fractional part is accepted here.
    frac = frac - (long)frac;  //Precautionary measure :-)
    int i, j;
    int[] res = new int[precs]; //For storing result.
    for(i = 0; i < precs && frac != 0; i++)
    {
        frac *= radix;
        res[i] = (int)frac;
        if((long)frac >= 1)
            frac = frac - (long)frac;
    }
    if(flag)
        return copy(res, i);
    return res;
}
```

The method that converts a number in base `radix` to decimal -- returns a `float`.

```
/**
 * This method returns a <code>float</code> that contains the equivalent of the
 * fraction in the other base in the parameter array, in decimal.
 * 
 * @param frac An <code>int[]</code> conatining only the fractional part.
 * @param radix The base of the fraction entered (must be (+) ve).
 * 
 * @return The equivalent decimal fraction as a <code>float</code>.
 */
public static float toDecimal(int[] frac, int radix)
{
    if(radix < 2) return null;
    float res = 0, fac = 1.0f/radix;
    int i, p = frac.length;
    for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        res += frac[i] * fac;        //or (float)Math.pow(radix, -i);
        fac/=radix;                  //would be fine as well.
    }
    return res;
}
```

### Finally! The `baseChanger()` method

```
public static int[] baseChanger(int[] f, int A, int B, int P)
{
    if(A < 2) return null;
    if(B < 2) return null;
    return toRadix(toDecimal(f, A), B, P);
}
```

And the `copy` method:

```
private static int[] copy(int[] a, int index)
{
    index = index < a.length ? index : a.length;
    int b[] = new int[index];
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        b[i] = a[i];
    return b;
}
```

---

I have obtained the required level of generalization. The results:

1. The actual (correct) output:

   [image: Best][image: Best2]
2. The output of the above written code:

   [image: OK][image: OK2]

So, I guess that settles it! By the way, here are some **tips**:

1. Working with arrays instead of `String` can lead to several
   complications. For starters, the integral part of the `float`
   entered is difficult to             deal with. This method is *okay*
   for the fractional part because we know where the loop is supposed
   to stop.
2. Using a `String` rules out the need for *copying*.
3. But your method has an upperhand : the upper limit for the `radix` is
   `Integer.MAX_VALUE` whereas that of the `String` approach is only 36 (0 to 9 and a to
   z) (though this is not quite a serious advantage as it has no practical application).
4. The most practical approach to changing the base of numbers is to *first* convert to 
   decimal and *then*, converting that to the other base.
5. Using `double` would be better than using `float` as it improves accuracy.

Comment: I'd say that is O(n). Congratulations.

Comment: Thanks! But the question is a little more general and asks for conversion between any two radixes. Could you possibly generalize?  Also, toRadix breaks on toRadix(frac, -1, precs).

Comment: I don't think -1 is a legitimate radix for a numbering system. Although, come to think of it, expressing numbers in base -2 might be funt: the first column is the ones, the second column is the -2s, the third column is the 4s, next the -8s… :)

Comment: Editing complete... Please take a look.

Comment: if(flag)
        return copy(res, i); // where do you set your flag variable?

Comment: @ambigram_maker Please see below (and try to break it if you wish).

Comment: @ambigram_maker from where did you use the Convert.baseChanger function which takes String as an argument and returns a String too instead of array?

Comment: @Somil You should take a look at the BlueJ interface in detail (although I don't use it anymore)

Comment: @ambigram_maker Yeah, I can see that, but from where can I get the code for that function

Comment: @Somil Well, I guess it shouldn't be too difficult to tweak the above code and get what you want. Best of luck! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This solution seems to work. It runs in O(NP) time and does not have overflows (as the carry has maximum B-1 = 2^31 - 1 - 1). Please let me know if you are able to break it; see below for test cases.

```
public class BaseTranslator {

    public static int[] convertBase(int[] f, int A, int B, int P)
    {
        if(A < 2) return null;
        if(B < 2) return null;
        if(P < 1) return null;
        if (f==null) return null;

        int[] converted = new int[P];
        int N = f.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if (f[i]<0 || f[i]>=A) return null;

        int[] copy = new int[N];

        for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {copy[i]=f[i];}

        int i = 0;

        for (i=0; i<P;i++) {
            int carry=0;

            for(int idx=N-1; idx>=0; idx--) {

                int x = copy[idx]*B + carry;
                int next = x % A;
                carry = x / A;

                copy[idx] = next;
            }

            converted[i]=carry;
        }


        return converted;  
    }
}
```

The following @Tests passed:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
public class BaseTranslatorTest {
    @Test
    public void basicBaseTranslatorTest() {
        // Expect that .01 in base-2 is .25 in base-10
        // (0 * 1/2^1 + 1 * 1/2^2 = .25)

        // corners

        /*  
         * If digits[i] < 0 or digits[i] >= baseA for any i, return null
         * If baseA < 2, baseB < 2, or precisionB < 1, return null 
         */

        int[] input = {1};

        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 2, 2, 1));

        // bad base and/or precision

        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 2, 2, 0));
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 2, 1, 1));
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 2, 1, 0));
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 1, 2, 1));
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 1, 2, 0));
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 1, 1, 1));
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 1, 1, 0));

        // bad input

        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{9,3,5,-2}, 10, 10, 1)); 
        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{9,3,5, 2}, 9, 9, 1));         

        // null input

        assertArrayEquals(null, BaseTranslator.convertBase(null, 1000000007, 1000000007, 1));  

        input = new int[]{0, 1};
        int[] expectedOutput = {2, 5};
        assertArrayEquals(expectedOutput, BaseTranslator.convertBase(input, 2, 10, 2));

        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,1}, 2, 2, 2));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,0,0,0}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,1}, 2, 2, 5));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,1}, 2, 2, 1));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2,5}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,1}, 2, 10, 2));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2,5,0,0,0}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,1}, 2, 10, 5));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,1}, 2, 10, 1));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{2,5}, 10, 2, 2));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,0,0,0}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{2,5}, 10, 2, 5));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{2,5}, 10, 2, 1));

        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,0,0,0,0}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0}, 1000000007, 314159, 5));

        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,1}, BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{3,1,2,5}, 10, 4, 2));


        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{0,0,0,0,3,0,5,1,7,5,7,8,1,2,5}, 10, 2, 15));



        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{4,8,1,4,8,1,4,8,1,4,8,1,4,8,1,4,8}, 
                          BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{1,1,1}, 3, 10, 17));

        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{12}, 
                          BaseTranslator.convertBase(new int[]{12}, 16, 16, 1));        

    }

}
```

Comment: I _broke_ your code. :-) and was able to find out a major flaw in the program. **It is not able to process recurring decimals.** `convertBase(new int[]{2}, 10, 2, 5)` gives `{0,0,0,0,0}` as result. it is able to work only on fixed length fractions.